# Как это понимать? массив не равен самому себе?

Tags: javascript

Как это понимать, если в случае
`0 == ['0'] // true` - это понятно, так как это разные типы и `0 === ['0']` возвращает false, то как быть с этим:

```
a = ['0'];

a == ['0'] возвращает false

a === ['0'] возвращает false

['0'] == ['0'] возвращает false

['0'] === ['0'] возвращает false
```

Comment: Представьте два листочка, на каждом одинаковые числа / цифра / другие объекты. Информация одна и та же, но листочки то разные :)

Comment: @moskalenco_a легендарное объяснение)

Comment: Переходите на Python. 
У вас логика нормальная, но не для этого языка программирования )

Answer (score 7):

Непримитивные типы данных сравниваются по ссылке, а не по значению. Каждый раз когда вы пишите `['0']` создаётся новый массив, а значит новая ссылка. Потому они между собой не равны

"0 == ['0'] // true - это понятно" - мне кажется вам это НЕ понятно. Тут применяется 11-ый пункт [алгоритма нестрого сравнения](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal), где говорится, что если слева у нас число, а справа объект, то будут сравниваться число с объектом, приведённым к примитивному типу. В случае массива вызовется метод `.toString()`, который нам вернёт `'0'`, вместо массива, а дальше идёт сравнение между 0 как число и 0 как строка

Этот случай описан в 5-ом пункте алгоритма, где говорится, что если слева число, а справа строка, то будут сравниваться число со строкой приведённой к типу числа, т.е. сработает `Number('0')`, что нам вернёт 0 как число

И так в итоге мы получаем `0 == 0` - это правда, значит мы получим `true`